# How to resolve Tomcat 9 not starting with Mojarra error

Tags: java, tomcat, jsx

I'm porting a Tomcat 6 app to Tomcat 9 I receive this error starting Tomcat:

```
30-Dec-2022 15:22:16.039 INFO [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/ordini'

SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/ordini] startup failed due to previous errors
30-Dec-2022 15:22:17.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\smiweb\tomcat-9.0.70\conf\Catalina\localhost\ordini.xml] has finished in [5,828] ms
30-Dec-2022 15:22:17.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\smiweb\tomcat-9.0.70\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml]
30-Dec-2022 15:22:17.679 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [] in deployment descriptor [C:\smiweb\tomcat-9.0.70\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml] has been ignored
30-Dec-2022 15:22:17.679 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\smiweb\tomcat-9.0.70\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml] with an external docBase means the directory [C:\smiweb\tomcat-9.0.70\webapps\ROOT] in the appBase will be ignored
30-Dec-2022 15:22:20.711 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name [smi] used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
30-Dec-2022 15:22:20.929 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
30-Dec-2022 15:22:20.992 INFO [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context ''
30-Dec-2022 15:22:20.992 WARNING [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized JSF1059: WARNING!  The com.sun.faces.verifyObjects feature is to aid developers not using tools.  It shouldn''t be enabled if using an IDE, or if this application is being deployed for production as it will impact application start times.
30-Dec-2022 15:22:21.586 INFO [main] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
30-Dec-2022 15:22:22.148 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved thank you I discovered there was a localhost log file and I found was missing a class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).